# multiple select get recently selected option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to know last or recently selected option value for dropdown

I have tried following code in django :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            django.jQuery("#id_emuhibah_issue").on("click", function(e){
                console.log(" click -------");
                console.log(django.jQuery(this).val());
                console.log(this.value);
            });
        });

        django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            django.jQuery("#id_emuhibah_issue").on("change", function(e){
                console.log(" chage -------");
                console.log(django.jQuery(this).val());
                console.log(this.value);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

seems there is no luck to find out last selected value

Can anyone suggest solution for above case?

Comment: `var previousElem = django.jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val()`

Comment: So what returns `console.log(this.value);`? Do you mean you want previously selected value or what? Maybe if i understand your expected behaviour, just use `mousedown` event instead of click or better set previous value in jq `data` object

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes! I want only last selected value. User can select multiple values in any order so I want last or recently selected one. `this.value` returns only last value for all selected values array and `console.log(django.jQuery(this).val());` returns array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I have manage to handle the case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
        return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
    };
    var old_selected_issues = [];
    django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        django.jQuery("#id_issue").on("change", function(e){
            var new_selected_issues = django.jQuery(this).val();
            if(new_selected_issues != null){
                var diff = new_selected_issues.diff(old_selected_issues);
                old_selected_issues = new_selected_issues;
                if(diff.length){
                    //perform the job on last selected option
                    var lang = window.location.pathname.slice(1,3)
                    django.jQuery("#issue_iframe").attr('src', '/'+lang+'/admin/'+diff[0]+'/');
                }
                else{
                    django.jQuery("#issue_iframe").attr('src', '');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                old_selected_issues = [];
                django.jQuery("#issue_iframe").attr('src', '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please let me know, in case of any other possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the click function and use only on.("change" function..) one function with one "document ready"

Comment: I have already tried that but that doesn't help me to achieve what I want

Comment: I want to get last selected value by user from selectbox